# Let $R$ be a ring with subring $S$ and ideal $I$ such that $I \cap S = 0$. Is it true $S + I = R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was originally solving the question:

> Let $S$ be a subring of $R$ and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Prove that if $S \cap I = 0$ then $\overline{S} \cong S$, where bar denotes the passage to $R/I$

By the Second Isomorphism Theorem, I can get the result $(S + I)/I \cong S$. But would it be true that $S + I = \lbrace s + i \mid s \in S, i \in I \rbrace  = R$? If not, how would you solve this question?

Comment: The problem doesn't ask you to show $S+I=R$. It only asks you to show that thee image of $S$ under the map $R\to R/I$, which is equal to $(S+I)/I$, is isomorphic to $S$, which you already did. You don't necessarily have $S+I=R$, and you don't need it. For an example, take $R=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, $I=\{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$, $S=\{(a,b,c)\in R\mid a=b=c\}$. Then $S\cap I=\{(0,0,0)\}$, and $S+I = \{(a,b,c)\in R\mid a=c\}\neq R$.

Comment: Arturo has already made the key points, but if you're still uncomfortable with why the image of $S$ under the canonical quotient map $R \to R/I$ is $(S+I)/I$, then the following justification may help. Note that $\overline{S}$ is the image of the composition of ring morphisms $S \to R \to R/I$, where the first map $S \to R$ is just the inclusion map. Clearly, $S$ surjects onto $\overline{S}$ via this composition by definition, so you just need to show that the kernel is trivial. Try to show that the kernel is exactly $S \cap I$.

Comment: Thank you both, Arturo and Alex !